# Change the size of a customized ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, size, drawable, extends

I created a CustomBar which extends ProgressBar, it has various methods to customize the appearance. One of this Functions adds a Icon to the progressing part. Since it's bigger that the ProgressBar it gets cropped, which I do not want.
So I tried changing the size of the ProgressBar when the Icon is added.

like this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
params.height = bitmap.getHeight();
setLayoutParams(params);

requestLayout();
```

This doesn't solve the problem, so I tried changing the size of the Drawable.
It's a LayerDrawable, I tried, setBounds, setLayerInsets, changing the first Layer to a InsetDrawable with padding to get the size I wanted. All to no avail.

So what am I missing? How to properly change the size of a progressBar at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself, you have to overwrite the bounds, but also for the Canvas.

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if(bitmap != null && bitmap.getHeight() > getHeight())
    {
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Region.Op.REPLACE); 

        bounds = getProgressDrawable().getBounds();
        bounds.bottom = bitmap.getHeight();
    }

    doSomething();
}
```

Important is the Region.Op.REPLACE flag, normally clipping just gets intersected with the Bounds of the Canvas.